# LINK2019 error, not sure why

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile my code and keep getting his with this error:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class iOrder const &)" (??6@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV01@ABViOrder@@@Z) referenced in function _main   C:\Users\on3m1_000\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Assign4\Assign4\a4main.obj Assign4
```

I'm totally unsure as to why this may be happening. The only thing I see in that error that looks even remotely like it's in my code is iOrder. If anyone can help give me any ideas as to why this is happening that would be great.

iorder header:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const iOrder& order);
```

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GS1Prefix.h"
#include "Order.h"

#define MAXORDERS 100
char menu(std::istream& is);
bool style(std::istream& is, char&);

int main() {
    char choice;
    int noOrders = 0;
    iOrder* order[MAXORDERS];
    Prefix prefix("prefixRanges.txt");

    std::cout << "Bookstore Order Processor\n"
        << "=========================\n";

    // process user input
    do {
        choice = menu(std::cin);
        std::cout << std::endl;
        switch (choice) {
        case 'P':
        {
                    EAN ean;
                    if (ean.read(std::cin, prefix)) {
                        int index = -1, created = false;
                        for (int i = 0; i < noOrders && index == -1; i++)
                        if (ean == order[i]->getEAN())
                            index = i;
                        if (index == -1)
                        if (noOrders < MAXORDERS) {
                            index = noOrders;
                            order[noOrders++] = new Order(ean);
                            created = true;
                        }
                        else
                            std::cerr << "No space for more orders!" << std::endl;
                        if (!order[index]->add(std::cin) && created)
                            delete order[--noOrders];
                    }
        }
            break;
        case 'S':
        {
                    EAN ean;
                    if (ean.read(std::cin, prefix)) {
                        int index = -1, created = false;
                        for (int i = 0; i < noOrders && index == -1; i++)
                        if (ean == order[i]->getEAN())
                            index = i;
                        if (index == -1)
                        if (noOrders < MAXORDERS) {
                            index = noOrders;
                            order[noOrders++] = new SpecialOrder(ean, "");
                            created = true;
                        }
                        else
                            std::cerr << "No space for more orders!" << std::endl;
                        if (!order[index]->add(std::cin) && created)
                            delete order[--noOrders];
                    }
        }
            break;
        case 'A':
        {
                    EAN ean;
                    if (ean.read(std::cin, prefix)) {
                        int index = -1;
                        for (int i = 0; i < noOrders && index == -1; i++)
                        if (ean == order[i]->getEAN())
                            index = i;
                        if (index != -1)
                            order[index]->add(1);
                        else
                            std::cerr << "No order for " << ean << " found!" << std::endl;
                    }
        }
            break;
        case 'D':
        {
                    EAN ean;
                    if (ean.read(std::cin, prefix)) {
                        int index = -1;
                        for (int i = 0; i < noOrders && index == -1; i++)
                        if (ean == order[i]->getEAN())
                            index = i;
                        if (index != -1)
                            order[index]->receive(std::cin);
                        else
                            std::cerr << "No order for " << ean << " found!" << std::endl;
                    }
        }
            break;
        case 'F':
        {
                    char s;
                    if (style(std::cin, s))
                    for (int i = 0; i < noOrders; i++)
                        order[i]->getEAN().style(s);
        }
            break;
        case 'V':
            std::cout << "              EAN  Ordered  Delivered Instructions\n";
            std::cout << "--------------------------------------------------\n";
            for (int i = 0; i < noOrders; i++) {
                std::cout << *order[i] << std::endl;
            }
            break;
        }
    } while (choice != 'Q');

    std::cout << "\nSigning off ... " << std::endl;
    // deallocate order memory
    for (int i = 0; i < noOrders; i++)
        delete order[i];
}

// menu prompts for and accepts an option selection from standard input and
// returns the character identifying the selected option
//
char menu(std::istream& is) {
    char c;
    int  ok = false;

    std::cout << '\n';
    std::cout << "Please select from the following options :\n";
    std::cout << " P - Place an order with a publisher\n";
    std::cout << " S - Place a special order with a publisher\n";
    std::cout << " A - Add one copy to an existing order\n";
    std::cout << " D - Record a delivery from a publisher\n";
    std::cout << " F - Change output style\n";
    std::cout << " V - View status of books on order\n";
    std::cout << " Q - Quit\n";
    do {
        std::cout << " Your selection : ";
        c = ' ';
        is.get(c);
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
            c -= 'a' - 'A';
        if (is.fail()) {
            is.clear();
            is.ignore(2000, '\n');
            std::cerr << " Invalid input.  Try again.\n";
        }
        else if (c == '\n') {
            ; // no input - try again
        }
        else if (c != 'P' && c != 'S' && c != 'A' && c != 'D' && c != 'V'
            && c != 'Q' && c != 'F') {
            is.ignore(2000, '\n');
            std::cerr << " Invalid Character.  Try again.\n";
        }
        else if (is.get() != '\n') {
            is.ignore(2000, '\n');
            std::cerr << " Trailing Characters.  Try Again.\n";
        }
        else if (c == 'P' || c == 'S' || c == 'A' || c == 'D' || c == 'V'
            || c == 'Q' || c == 'F')
            ok = true;
    } while (ok == 0);

    return c;
}

// style prompts for and accepts the style from input stream is
//
bool style(std::istream& is, char& s) {
    bool rc = false, ok = false;
    char c;
    do {
        std::cout << " EAN Style ('-', ' ', '\\n' or '0' to quit) : ";
        c = ' ';
        is.get(c);
        if (is.fail()) {
            is.clear();
            is.ignore(2000, '\n');
            std::cerr << " Invalid input. Try again.\n";
        }
        else if (c != '-' && c != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != '0') {
            is.ignore(2000, '\n');
            std::cerr << " Invalid Character.  Try again.\n";
        }
        else if (c == '0') {
            if (is.get() != '\n') {
                is.ignore(2000, '\n');
                std::cerr << " Trailing Characters.  Try Again.\n";
            }
            else
                ok = true;
        }
        else if (c == '\n') {
            ok = true;
            s = '\0';
            rc = true;
        }
        else if (is.get() != '\n') {
            is.ignore(2000, '\n');
            std::cerr << " Trailing Characters.  Try Again.\n";
        }
        else if (c == '-' || c == ' ') {
            ok = true;
            s = c;
            rc = true;
        }
    } while (!ok);

    return rc;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you reduce code to simplify the problem?

Comment: move `#include "ean.h"` from `iorder.h` to `iorder.cpp` and don't include any file in a header file of class. **Where is the implemention of** `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const iOrder& order);`

Comment: Keep removing code till you find the smallest code which can repro the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare and use this operator:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const iOrder& order);
```

but you haven't written any code for it (or at leats it isn't in the shown code)

Comment: Thank you! that was the problem, fixed the typo and now it works fine.